# how to calculate the render time of two gpu together?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

One renders in about 1 minute and the other in 30 sec, how long are the two together?
I can't activate both because I'm still going to buy one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated question, and takes a whole number of parameters, including your card configuration. Are you using SLI or no SLI?

If we initially consider the VRAM in an SLI configuration, the maximum VRAM used by the render engine will be determined by the max of the smaller card, so right away if you're using two different cards you could be hindering yourself, and would be better off with just having the more powerful card by itself. If they're both the same cards then this won't matter.

If the scene you want to render have very large textures or needs to use more RAM than what is available on the graphics cards, the scene will fail and not render, and the number of cards doesn't have any impact on this.

Have you tried using CPU + GPU rendering, you'll see a big bump in performance over that of a single GPU, and wouldn't cost you anymore money, whilst buying a second card would.

Comment: my processor has a built-in video card... and I'm looking to buy a video card to improve rendering performance... and I'm wondering if it's worth it, if it's going to improve the rendering time if you put the two together

Comment: oh okay this is a different story altogether. Your CPU has an integrated graphics processing unit. These are by far and away inferior in comparison to a dedicated GPU. For blender I recommend an NVIDIA GPU, as blender benefits from CUDA acceleration, a feature that only NVIDIA cards provide as of right now, what card were you looking at, I can provide some recommendations if you're unsure as well

Comment: so I was seeing a GeForce GTX 1070 SC, but I wanted to know if putting the processor with built-in video + a new card would have a better performance than just the new card

Comment: just to clarify as you're not being completely clear can you provide the spec of your current machine, i'll assume you'll be adding the gtx 1070 SC to this machine